# .Net6 updating Program.cs minimal hosting model with IServiceCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-6.0

Just starting to try and understand the changes with .Net6 and the Program.cs and the minimal hosting model.

I've hit a problem attempting to update a piece of code which deals with Dependency Injection and transform it to work with the new model.

I have a Single solution containing 2 projects, and I have a problem updating the Program.cs in order to get the Dependency Injection updated.

The following is the DbContext.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WorkRequest.Data.Models;

namespace WorkRequest.Data.Context
{
    public partial class WorkRequestContext : DbContext
    {
        public WorkRequestContext()
        {
        }

        public WorkRequestContext(DbContextOptions<WorkRequestContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<RequestType> RequestType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<RequestForm> RequestForm { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AssignedTo> AssignedTo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the RegisterDataServices class which contains the Dependency Injection setup information

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SETWorkRequest.Data.Context;

namespace WorkRequest.Data
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection RegisterDataServices(
            this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<WorkRequestContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.
                GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            return services;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I would usually place code in the Startup.cs but obviously that isn't a thing anymore in .Net6.

This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work.  I get the Error CS0103 'configuration' doesn't exist in the current context.

The line in question is:

'builder.Services.RegisterDataServices(configuration);'

```
using WorkRequest.Data;

namespace WorkRequest.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.RegisterDataServices(configuration);

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried all the Intellisense suggestions but nothing works.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: `builder.Services.RegisterDataServices(builder.Configuration);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have to create variable of Configuration from WebApplicationBuilder like as below:

> IConfiguration configuration = builder.Configuration;

After that, we can use that configuration:

> builder.Services.RegisterDataServices(configuration);